# Can anyone steal the powers of Devil Fruit from another?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, Blackbeard stole someone's power.

Other than him, can anyone steal the powers of another? For instance, Sanji taking the Clear-Clear Fruit of Absalom (that was just an example since it didn't really happen).

Comment: since the process of stealing a devils fruit power is still unclear, we can only speculate if other could do it to.

Comment: I can come up with reasons to close this... it can be interpreted as broad, unclear, or about unknown future events.  This is, however, is no way opinion based.  Why the 4 of you voted that way I can't imagine.

Comment: The only way apart from killing that i can think of is possibly through the darkness devil fruit, the range of abilities for the yami yami no mi is still not completely known. However, it is possible because blackbeard stole whitebeards  tremble abilities . Also, burges wanted to capture luffy and steal his powers. this shows that blackbeards crew most definitely know a method of stealing the fruits and i'm guessing it is most likely connected to the darkness df

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin I agree Blackbeard has a way. I have no verifiable idea what that way is.  It may just be killing as no one I've seen (im not 100% up to date) has had their DF removed and survived. His Cerberus... sorry.... i mean... His Darkness DF might just explain why he an have multiple DF.

Answer (score 4):

You can if you don't already have a DF.

Usually if you want a person's DF power, you kill that person.  The power will transfer to a nearby fruit and that fruit will become a DF.  Once you consume that fruit you have their power.

If you want to take the power by another means.... we don't know.  It is currently unknown how or if Devil Fruits can transfer from one living person to another without going through the normal cycle. There are two suspicious cases of DF transfer: Blackbeard obtaining Whitebeard's power and Lin Lin Charlotte obtaining Mother Caramel's power. Several details about both mysteries seem intentionally obscured so that no answer to this question is possible yet.

Similar discussions could be had about multiple DF powers, objects eating DF, or limits of speculated DF powers.  At this point though the discussions are largely fruitless (ironically) as the answer has to be "we don't and can't know yet".

Answer (score 0):

There are some devil fruits like "Luck Luck Fruit" which can steal luck of other people. 
Smoothie also steals others power to be bigger and bigger.
Moria can steal others ' shadow(power too).

There are several such powers and fruits in One Piece World!

Comment: I want to upvote you because you are right but I think OP meant Devil Fruit Powers.